# Is this "satellite photo" the only representation of the shape of Gilligan's Island?

Tags: map, setting, gilligans-island

From [How many independent demonstrations of optical communications between ground and space have been successful?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/48558/12102)

> As everybody knows, the pioneering work of The Professor and his serendipitous collaborator Gilligan demonstrated the reality of ground to space optical communications back in 1964 [Splashdown, S3E22](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0588095/). In that case information was encoded in the incandescent radtaion of soot particles via *spatial modulation*<sup>1</sup> rather than the more modern *temporal modulation*.
>
> The launch of this crewed and remarkable mission can be seen [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/25636/12102).

**Question:** In *either* the real world or in-island (in-universe), was this the only time that any depiction of the shape of the *eponymously nicknamed* Gilligan's Island was shown? If there were others, do the shapes agree?

---

[image: Gilican's Island seen from space, from Splashdown, S3E22]

Gilligan's Island as seen from space (low Earth orbit), from Splashdown, S3E22. [source](https://gilligan.fandom.com/wiki/Splashdown)

---

<sup>1</sup> https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0588095/mediaviewer/rm2807151617

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We see multiple version of [the island](https://gilligan.fandom.com/wiki/The_Island) map in various episodes. They're all largely similar to the high altitude map shown in *Splashdown*.

[image: Map of the island from Forward March.]
<sub><sup>**Map of the island from Forward March.**</sup></sub>

[image: Map of the island from Man With a Net.]
<sub><sup>**Map of the island from Man With a Net.**</sup></sub>

[image: Map of the island from Hi-Fi Gilligan]
<sub><sup>**Map of the island from Hi-Fi Gilligan**</sup></sub>

Comment: "They're all largely similar to the high altitude map shown in *Splashdown*." - err ... the first two ones in this answers are unquestionably similar to each other. However, I fail to see any noteworthy similarity between those two, the third one, or the one from the question, beyond being islands with a non-convex outline.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - It helps if you turn the pictures upside and squint a little

Comment: "topologically equivalent"

Comment: @OrganicMarble as you know by now I simply can not stop asking questions! (nor the overuse of exclamation points) [When can we say that two representations of an island's shore line are topologically equivalent? Is Luzon an instructive case?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3912083/284619)