# How many times did Gilligan's Island castaways interact with astronauts and/or space capsules?

Tags: gilligans-island

In [Is this "satellite photo" the only representation of the shape of Gilligan's Island?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/239273/51174) I recall [*Splashdown*, S3E22](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0588095/) with US astronauts in orbit, then safely landing somewhere (I don't recall where), but [this comment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/50496/what-does-it-take-to-upgrade-a-radio-antenna-to-receive-from-the-surface-of-mars#comment164519_50496) in Space Exploration SE links to the video [Gilligan's Island - The Russians Have Landed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OUm_3Lmo1zM) that shows a space-suited Soviet-era astronaut being interrogated by Ginger, acting the role of a [honeytrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honey_trapping).

And I have a *vague memory only* of a capsule floating in the lagoon but no idea from which episode it's from. I seem to remember that it looked more like a [Project Mercury](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Mercury) capsule than a Soviet capsule.

**Question:** How many times did Gilligan's island castaways interact with astronauts? Is it just the fiery "SOS" they sent from the beach in one episode ([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=US_4gi_qHFs)) and the actual appearance of two Soviet astronauts on the island in the other, or are there more?

Is the floating lagoon in the capsule I'm remembering the one that the Soviet astronauts used, or is it from the US astroanuts, or is that  from yet another episode?

[image: MA-9 Faith 7 Space Center Houston, Houston, TX.JPG] Mercury capsule, [Source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:MA-9_Faith_7_Space_Center_Houston,_Houston,_TX.JPG) (click for larger)

Comment: There was also an episode where a Venus/Mars probe landed, they ended up tar and feathering themselves and looking like big chickens (to Mission Control) when the probe camera turned on. It MOGHT have landed in the lagoon and the professor had to fix it so it would operate.

Comment: Is Gilligan's Island so science-fictional that every aspect of the show, including non-sci-fi stuff like astronauts and space capsules, is on topic here?

Comment: @user14111 only these aspects are science fiction; the question is carefully and narrowly scoped to ensure that it remains on-topic and that answers did not stray. General questions about the series would of course be off-topic, but fictional stories of "unexpected visitors from outer space" is 100% science fiction.

Comment: So  you're saying that fictional stories about astronauts, created at a time when there are real astronauts, are science fiction? Even when they don't involve any imaginative stuff life space monsters or voyages to other planets?

Comment: @user14111 I don't respond to "so what you're saying is..."s. My comment is clear an concise as-is, and this question is fine; generalizations and site policy-making belong in meta.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Just sit right back and you'll hear a tale
>
> A tale [from Space Exchange](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/50496/what-does-it-take-to-upgrade-a-radio-antenna-to-receive-from-the-surface-of-mars?noredirect=1#comment164540_50496)
>
> That started with a Moon hoaxer
>
> And now I'm reading the [Gillian's Island wiki](https://gilligan.fandom.com/) and can't think of a rhyme.

- [Splashdown](https://gilligan.fandom.com/wiki/Splashdown) features the US ["Scorpio EX-1"](https://gilligan.fandom.com/wiki/Scorpio_EX-1) space capsule.

[image]

- [Nyet, Nyet, Not Yet](https://gilligan.fandom.com/wiki/Nyet,_Nyet,_Not_Yet) features two Cosmonauts and their capsule. Looks like the same prop painted orange.

[image]

## Honorable Mentions

- [Meet the Meteor](https://gilligan.fandom.com/wiki/Meet_the_Meteor) featured the eponymous meteor.

[image]

- [Smile, You're On Mars Camera](https://gilligan.fandom.com/wiki/Smile,_You%27re_on_Mars_Camera) featured a [Mars probe](https://gilligan.fandom.com/wiki/Mars_Probe) they tried to use to signal for help.

[image]

- [Gilligan's Living Doll](https://gilligan.fandom.com/wiki/Gilligan%27s_Living_Doll) featured the XR-1000, an Air Force robot.

[image]

- [It's a Bird, It's a Plane, It's Gilligan](https://gilligan.fandom.com/wiki/It%27s_a_Bird,_It%27s_a_Plane) featured the XJP Jet Pack washed up on shore.

[image]

Comment: @uhoh I don't know what's worse. Arguing with Moon hoaxers or combing through the Gilligan's Island wiki. The price you must pay is to listen to [Puddles Pity Party's Stairway To Gilligan's Island](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K4MKQMTHplI).

Comment: I have now paid the price, full screen full volume and looked Puddles in the eye the whole time, remembering when the song first came out and imagining what it would have been like knowing then what I'd be seeing and doing now! Your gilligan.fandom link shows the capsule appeared earlier in [It's About Time](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FQDRJ9aK0mY) which began [like this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DsJhBn0I9U4).

Comment: Awesome special effects! Even as a kid I thought the Scorpio EX-1 was mighty roomy inside.

Comment: I guess the forgettable episode with the Japanese sailor in his mini-sub doesn't rise to any type of mention, let alone an honorable one.